# How to get browser display height and width using javascript

Tags: javascript, height, width

[image]

I have been suffering to get it how to get height and width of displayed pic browser width(without scroll bar) and height(without tootlbar and taskbar and address)

Answer (score 3):

You can get browser dimensions with javascript using `window.innerHeight`.

```
var h=window.innerHeight;
```

You can use the `innerWidth` for width too. There is a table with browser compatibility at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp).